# Trying to add BaseGameUtils to LibGdx project in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, libgdx, google-play-services

So I have a LibGdx game which I want to add Google play services to. I am using android studio but I can't find any good tutorials.

I have the BaseGameUtils in the root directory of my game. My settings.gradle file looks like

```
include 'android', 'ios', 'core', 'BaseGameUtils'
```

I added **compile project(':BaseGameUtils')** to the android dependencies of my build.gradle file which works fine and I can use the classes in the android project fine. However I can't access the classes in the core project and I want to pass a GameHandler to the game so that I can use achievements and leaderboards.

So I tried adding the same line to the core section of the gradle file so that it looked like

```
project(":core") {
apply plugin: "java"


dependencies {
    compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx:$gdxVersion"
    compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d:$gdxVersion"
    compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype:$gdxVersion"
    compile fileTree(dir: '../libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile project(':BaseGameUtils')
}
}
```

but this results in an error.

Android studio gives me this **core depends on libraries but is not a library itself** error

Answer (score 2):

You cannot compile *BaseGameUtils* in *core* because the *BaseGameUtils* source requires Android libraries.

If you look at these tutorials ([Fortheloss Games](http://fortheloss.org/tutorial-set-up-google-services-with-libgdx/), and others available on the [libGDX Wiki](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Google-Play-Game-Services-in-LibGDX)) you have to pass down the *AndroidLauncher* class to your *Game* class. Then, since no other platform but Android can use the Google Libraries then the Desktop, HTML, and iOS targets will have fake methods that don't actually do anything.

Also, an error you may encounter (or you already have), the Android API versions of the *BaseGameUtils* and libGDX are different, so you may need to go into the BaseGameUtils and change its *AndroidManifest.xml* file.

Hope this helps!